# Charaterize the boundary of the set $\{A \in \star: \max_i \text{Re}(\lambda_i(A)) < 0\}$ where $\star$ is some structure on $M_5(\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology

Let us parametrize $M_5(\mathbb R)$ by 10 parameters $(a_1, \dots a_5, b_1, \dots, b_5)$ in following way 
\begin{align}
\tag{$\star$}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -a_1 & 0 & 0 & -b_1 \\
1 & -a_2 & 0 & 0 & -b_2 \\
0 & -a_3 & 0 & 0 & -b_3 \\
0 & -a_4 & 1 & 0 & -b_4 \\
0 & -a_5 & 0 &1 & -b_5
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Let us define a set $\mathcal H$ and $\mathcal E$ by
\begin{align*}
&\mathcal H = \{A \in (\star): \max_i \text{Re}(\lambda_i(A)) < 0\},\\
&\mathcal E = \{A \in (\star): \max_i \text{Re}(\lambda_i(A)) = 0\},
\end{align*}
i.e., matrices parametrized as $\star$ having the largest real part of all eigenvalues lying on the left open half plane and imaginary axis respectively. Naively, I would think the boundary of $H$ is given by $\partial H = \mathcal E$. But I have not been able to prove it. Obviously $\partial H \subset \mathcal E$.

Let
\begin{align*}
\mathcal F =  \{A \in \mathcal E: A \text{ has distinct eigenvalues}\}.
\end{align*}
I have shown $\mathcal H$ is connected and for every $M \in \mathcal F$, I can show $M \in \partial H$. But no further. I tried to show $\mathcal F$ is dense in $\mathcal E$ but according to an answer here [Are matrices diagonalizable dense in a specific parametrization of $M_5(\mathbb R)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993572/are-matrices-diagonalizable-dense-in-a-specific-parametrization-of-m-5-mathbb), it is not an easy question to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer.

Let $A=((a_i),(b_i))\in \star$.

Let $f:(a_i),(b_i)\in\mathbb{R}^{10}\rightarrow \chi_A(x)\in Z\approx \mathbb{R}^5$,

where $Z$ is the set of monic real polynomials of degree $5$.

$\textbf{Proposition}$. If $A\in\mathcal{E},rank(Df_A)=5$, then there is a sequence in $\mathcal{H}$ that tends to $A$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. There are a neighborhood $U$ of   $(a_i,b_j)$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $\chi_A$ -a polynomial that admits roots $u_1,\cdots,u_k$ with $<0$ real part and roots $v_1,\cdots,v_{5-k}$ with $0$ real part- and charts $\psi,\phi$ of $U,V$ s.t.

$\psi^{-1}\circ f\circ\phi$ is the projection $(x_i)_{i\leq 10}\in\mathbb{R}^{10}\rightarrow (x_i)_{i\leq 5}\in\mathbb{R}^5$.

In $V$, there is a polynomial $q$ that admits the roots $u_1,\cdots,u_k,v'_1,\cdots,v'_{5-k}$ where the $v'_i$  have $<0$ real part. It suffices to consider a small perturbation of $\psi^{-1}(\phi(q),0_5)$ (in order to obtain distinct roots). $\square$

For a generic $A$, $rank(Df_A)=5$ and we may use the above proposition. Unfortunately, in general, $rank(Df_A)\geq 3$ and, in particular, $rank(Df_A)=3$ when the $(a_i),(b_j)$ are $0$.

In this last case, despite many random tests, I did not find small variations that send $A$ to an element of $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask how you compute the rank of the differential? Do you computer the formula for characteristic polynomial and then look at the differential matrix? Or is there some clever way to see it?

Comment: No, I calculate the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty.